# How can I use one commit for git main and sub modules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Let's say I have a project(UI) which has a git submodule(Data layer). I'll often change both the submodule and the main git repo. Is it possible to modify files in both and commit them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're in two separate repositories, so no, a single commit can't be used to commit both of them.  In fact, since submodules usually exist in a "detached HEAD" state, you don't want to commit there without making sure you're going to generate reachable commits.

You could probably write a short shell script to take care of this for you (that is, you run the shell script with a commit message and it takes care of making all the necessary commits), but this is going to be a little tricky -- committing a change in the submodule will require a commit in the parent repository, so the order in which you do things is important.  Ensuring that the submodule is not in a detached state *should* be a simple `git checkout master`, but what if that fails?

If you are often changing both at the same time, are you sure they need to be separate repositories?